# is there a way to define datatypes firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm wondering if there is a way to define any kind of data schema in firebase? I could find anything like this.
I'm currently investigating firebase for a project and was wondering if it is possible to define inside firebase how a certain object and it's properties look like.

From mongoose in know, that is very helpfull to have a server side object model to prevent the client from writing erroneous data to the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/understanding-security.html) and more specifically the [Blaze security language](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-08-21-blaze-security-language.html), you could enforce a schema on the Firebase data tree.
From the linked post:

> Developers that use denormalization may find they repeat whole subtrees of information in multiple places in a Firebase. The Blaze language caters for reuse of subtrees by allowing schemas to be defined and reused many times.

The Blaze language would let you define things like this example:

```
schema:
  definitions:
   message:
     type: object
     properties:
       from:    {type: string}
       to:      {type: string}
       message: {type: string}

$userid:
  properties:
    inbox:
      $messages: {$ref: "#/definitions/message"}
    outbox:
      $messages: {$ref: "#/definitions/message"}
```